# Cannot modify variables in switch case in Swift

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I am trying to update the value of a variable (inside the function) inside the switch case construct. I am new to swift and am not sure I understand why it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
var val = 0
for (index, message) in messages.enumerated() {
if index > 3 {
    break
}
myFunc(one: sentMessage, two: message, link: "link") { results in
    switch results {
    case .success(let genres):
        // use genres here, e.g. update model and UI
        val = max(val, Int(genres)!)
        print(val)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
}
print(val)
```

The myFunc referenced here is:

```
private func myFunc(one: String, two: String, link: String, completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
        
        let url = URL(string: link)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "parent" : one,
            "original": two
        ]
        request.httpBody = parameters.percentEncoded()
        var responseString = ""
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data,
                  let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                  error == nil else {                                              // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error", error ?? "Unknown error")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.failure(error as! Error))
                }
                return
            }
            
            guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else {                    // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.failure(error!))
                }
                return
            }
            
            responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
            //            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.success(responseString))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

The value of `val` printed inside the switch case is different but when it is printed outside it it reverts to its default value. I want to update inside the switch case forever. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you please provide the code for the `func` function? and whats the context of this code? where do you execute it? is it playground, app or a simple script?

Comment: Where are you calling the function?

Comment: I am calling this function inside another function.

Comment: `myFunc` is asynchronous, and so your second `print(val)` will be executed _before_ the assignment. That's a feature, not a bug. To see the assigned value, move the `print` inside the completion handler.

Comment: @Gereon I see, but can I make the function execute first? Because that is crucial for I am trying to achieve

Comment: No, you can't fight asynchronicity. Instead, embrace it and run the code that needs to run after the network request returns in its completion handler.